# TFSBuildServiceHost start error referencing Elmah SQLite.dll

Tags: tfs

Installed the TFS 2010 build service and when trying to start the tfsbuildservicehost I get the following errror (this is on a Windows Server 2008, patched and updated, and we are not using SQLite).  This is happening twice for the build controller, the build agent and the build service.

> TFSBuildServiceHost
>
> Service 'MVC Build Agent' had an
>   exception:  Exception Message: Problem
>   with loading custom assemblies: API
>   restriction: The assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\1\Utilities\Elmah\lib\x64\System.Data.SQLite.DLL'
>   has already loaded from a different
>   location. It cannot be loaded from a
>   new location within the same
>   appdomain. (type Exception)

Comment: I don't know what the 'MVC Build Agent' is, but it's not a component of Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problem:)

Go to your controller definition in tfs and in build controller properties and set version control path to custom assemblies and add there location to your
`"Elmah\lib\x64\System.Data.SQLite.DLL"` from your tfs project.
in format of :

**$/Elmah/lib**

this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the 'MVC Build Agent' is, but it's not a component of Team Foundation Server. Sounds like you have a custom assembly that's failing to load. Check the build controller properties to see where it's looking for its custom assemblies. You'll need to either (a) check-in the dependencies required by this custom assembly, or (b) change/remove the custom assembly path for the build controller so it no longer tries to load it.

Comment: Jim, the MVC Build Agent was just the name I gave to the TFSBuildAgent service.  Since you can have have more then one build going at a time,  it allows you to name them to keep track of which tfs agent is working on which build.